# SQL Compact: Force .NET to use a private installation?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am developing an app that uses a SQL Compact 4.0 private installation. I have SQL Compact installed globally on my development machine, so to test the private installation, I have to create an installer and deploy to a machine that doesn't have SQL Compact 4.0.

Here's my question: Is there a way to force my development machine to ignore the global installation (short of uninstalling it) and rely exclusively on the private installation that I have set up? It would save me time debugging the private install. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the GACed ADO Provider (System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll) in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop and in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop.

Remember to use the 4.0.0.1 assembly version provider in your project (from the Private folder), either as a reference or via config.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Your blog post on private deployment was very helpful: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html